# ¿Cómo puedo extraer un dato en un cadena de tipo Srting en java?

Tags: java

```
 - U1;peru;2018-09-19;4752
 - U1;bolivia;2018-12-24;1099
 - U1;peru;2016-08-01;800
```

tengo tres registros de tipo string por ejemplo "U1;peru;2018-09-19;4752" me gustaria extraer ciertos valores de una ciudad en particular en este caso ejemplo seria peru seria 4752 y y el otro del otro registro 800 y sumarlos. ¿como le haria ?

Comment: Los campos de los registros siempre van a ser fijos? Es decir, siempre van a llegar en ese orden?

Comment: @NahuelGiani si la estructura es la misma pero se debe poder buscar de algun pais en especifico si es peru deben ser el valor 4752 y 800. y si es otro deben ser los valores del tal paid

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por la estructura del string, estan separados por ";" yo te recomendaría hacer un loop en cada string en donde guardo carácter por carácter hasta encontrar un ";" ahi lo guardado meterlo a una lista.
segun entiendo
[U1;peru;   2018-09-19;4752]
ID; Nombre; Fecha; numero

```
String s="U1;peru;2018-09-19;4752";
    ArrayList L = new ArrayList();
    String s1 = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i)!=';') {
            s1+=s.charAt(i);
        }else{
            L.add(s1);
            s1="";
        }
    }
    L.add(s1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < L.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("["+i+"] -> "+L.get(i));
    }
```

yo lo haría de esta manera, primero hay que segmentar el string otra forma seria usar la función split del objeto Sting

Answer (score 2):

Si la estructura es siempre la misma o el valor a tomar es siempre el ultimo puedes usar la funcion `split` para strings.

```java
String cadena = "U1;peru;2018-09-19;4752";
String[] valores = cadena.split(";");
```

> Ten en cuenta que en esta caso el caracter separador es `;`

Por lo tanto solo tendrias que tomar el ultimo valor de `valores`

```java
valores[valores.length()-1];
```

Los datos en valores seran los siguientes:

```java
valores[0];//U1
valores[1];//peru
valores[2];//2018-09-19
valores[3];//4752
```